# The variable is either undeclared or was never assigned and rebuilding does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have the same problem that has been asked here and over at the MS forums a lot - I have a combobox control and a string array, so I assign the string array to the combobox in

Form1.Designer.cs

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
...
this.ComboBox_Target_0.Items.AddRange(Ranks);
...
}
```

the array, itself is declared like so:

```
string[] Ranks = { "Rank 1", "Rank 2", "Rank 3", "Rank 4", "Rank 5", "Rank 6", "Rank 7", "Rank 8", "Rank 9", "Rank 10", "Rank 11", "Rank 12" };
```

If I build my solution the form runs fine and the combobox has all the items listed and it works fine. However the form designer refuses to start saying "The variable Ranks is either undeclared or was never assigned".

I have seen the other questions about this same problem and have already tried their (only) solution - to rebuild the solution, close VS and open it back up. But that didn't help. I tried putting the string array in "InitializeComponent()" and "public Form1()", rebuilding and etc. each time. However it has not fixed itself for me.

Let me just check - choosing "Ignore and Continue" in this case would not jeopardize anything, right?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that you shouldn't modify the designer file. If there's some reason you need those values available at design time, and you don't want to use the editor, the only way I got it to work without an error is to put this at the very top of the `InitializeComponent` method:

```
string[] Ranks = new string[] { "Rank 1", "Rank 2", "Rank 3", "Rank 4", "Rank 5", "Rank 6", "Rank 7", "Rank 8", "Rank 9", "Rank 10", "Rank 11", "Rank 12" };
```

I added `new string[]` to the declaration. This is based on how the editor will create the list at design time:

```
this.ComboBox_Target_0.Items.AddRange(new object[] {...
```

After defining `Ranks` like that, your line will work:

```
this.ComboBox_Target_0.Items.AddRange(Ranks);
```

If you only need the values at runtime, it's better to do it like this (or a variant thereof):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] Ranks = { "Rank 1", "Rank 2", "Rank 3", "Rank 4", "Rank 5", "Rank 6", "Rank 7", "Rank 8", "Rank 9", "Rank 10", "Rank 11", "Rank 12" };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ComboBox_Target_0.Items.AddRange(Ranks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I do it like this, because there are a lot of comboboxes, actually, that I want to use the same items and I also want to be able to easily edit the contents of the array in the future, if need be. I have no idea what it means to only need the values at runtime vs to not.

Comment: It simply means that if you are just designing the form ("design mode") and don't need the values until the application is run ("runtime"), it is better to use the runtime method. That way you aren't interfering with the designer file. You can still populate multiple boxes with the range.